# Where Equals Subquery Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I convert the following SQL query to Laravel:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE some_column = 
(
    SELECT some_column 
    FROM SomeTable st1 
    where st1.some_column2 = SomeTable.some_column2 
)
```

This query is just an example query. I know that Laravel has a whereIn function for subqueries. I am looking for something similar about equality of a column with a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::table('SomeTable')
->select('*')
->where('some_column','=',function($query) {
    $query->from('SomeTable')
        ->select('some_column')
        ->where('SomeTable.some_column2','=',DB::raw('SomeTable.some_column2'));
})
->get();
```

Comment: Sidenote, Laravel has a `whereColumn()` method: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereColumn. You can use that like `whereColumn('st1.some_column2', 'SomeTable.some_column2')` instead of `where(..., DB::raw(...))` as suggested here.